# pandox coverting tex to docx - cannot convert tables correctly

Tags: pdftex, pandoc

Trying to convert my tex document to word (docx) format using pandoc for a challenged colleague. I notice most of it converts nicely, but tables get rendered as plain text eg.

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l|l}
        Process Area & Description \\
        \hline
        Service Monitoring        & Confirm if Contract Register complies. 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

comes out in word as

```
to Process Area & Description
Service Monitoring & Confirm if Contract Register complies.
```

Note the "to" at the start is definitely not in the source text

I am using `pandoc report.tex --reference-doc=reference.docx -o report.docx` as my pandoc command

Comment: Report such issues in the pandoc github. (And better don't use tabu, it is broken. See the readme here: https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu).

Comment: If you can indeed reproduce this with `tabular` then it would be useful to add an example of that to your question. Such an example might convince potential answerers to start looking for a solution, instead of just thinking 'it's `tabu`, that is broken anyway'.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. If I run your snippet through pandoc I get a nice table in word. Which version of pandoc are you using? What happens if you leave out `--reference-doc=reference.docx `?

Comment: hmm must be another package I'm running

Comment: pandoc 1.16.0.2 under ubuntu 16.04 - I suspect this might be the cause.. I've stripped down to a basic mwe and still get no tables..